# Excel Solver - Useful methods to "kick" Nonlinear solutions out of a stuck point

Tags: excel, solver, non-linear

I'm running Excel Solver using the Nonlinear method (because the problem is much too nonlinear to suggest using any other method).  There are over 40 variables, so there are over 80 constraints - some binary and most numerical > or<.
I have implemented a few "different" solver criteria for the end point in a time series including:

- maximize the value,
- maximize the percentage gain in that same value,
- maximize the compound gain in that same value,
- maximize the sum of the percentage gain and the compound gain (which makes no real sense but introduces a "difference" to the Solver).
  These are attempts at "kicking" the problem so that a broader range of possibilities might be found.  And, it does work .. to a point.
  Of course, this is because Solver is "canned" with no internal access.  And, I can't venture away from Excel for now.
  I'm asking if there are other methods to force Solver Nonlinear problems to move around the solution space?

Comment: Excel solver isn't all that great even at solving problems even with half a dozen variables. If your model has 40 variables then you might want to think about simplifying it to the parameters that really make the most difference. Incidentally the people who wrote Solver have a website and flog a whole host of expensive optimiser add-ons for Excel. Simulated annealing is my favourite method for finding a decent approximation to a global optimum and it has the advantage of not easily getting stuck (unlike conjugate gradient search algorithms which are great for a final polish).

Comment: @Martin: I have considered implementing something like simulated annealing in Excel for this.  Your suggestion brings it into focus.  It seems there are nothing but "expensive" add-ons for that.  Maybe scipy.optimize anneal would be a less expensive choice.

Comment: @Martin: The main limitation about Excel solve for a simple desktop environment is that these larger problems can be slow.  This one takes a few minutes.  More if repeating shows improvement.  I find that iterating with repeated runs can work - often only to confirm no further improvement or that it's stuck.

Comment: Sticking with Excel then your best bet is to try and identify the parameter(s) with the strongest influence and probe  a grid based on the 2 or 3 most promising ones to choose potential starting points. One problem I see often with Solver is that it cannot always find the right (accurate) answer to fairly simple problems. Close but no cigar... You should be able to cook up a simulated annealing code in VBA it isn't a massively complex algorithm. It is sl-o--w! You probably would be better off with established optimisation code though.